# If tar is interrupted, it overwrites the first file it operates on. Is there any way I can prevent this?

Tags: linux, ssh, tar, file-transfer

I'm trying to quickly transfer hundreds to thousands of small files over ssh by creating a tar archive of them and transferring them over ssh.

My local system is running Linux Mint 18.1 and my remote system is running Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

For example, suppose I have the directory

```
/var/www/testing
```

and several files and subfolders inside of it.

```
/var/www/testing/subdir1/*
/var/www/testing/subdir2/*
/var/www/testing/file1
/var/www/testing/file2
/var/www/testing/file3
```

I want to transfer all of these files to myself. Because there are so many and ssh transfers files slowly one by one, I'm creating an archive of them and transferring the archive:

```
ssh user@domain "cd /var/www; tar zcvf - testing" | "tar zxvf -"
```

This works perfectly, provided that the tar command does not get interrupted. If tar gets interrupted, the first file, in this case *file1*, is overwritten as a partial archive including every file up to the file it got interrupted on.

Is there something I'm doing that is causing this? How can I avoid this, or are there better ways to quickly transfer a large number of files?

Comment: Have you looked at `rsync`? It will not overwrite a target file until the whole file has been transferred. It will also only copy the files that are new or have changed, and can be restarted to continue where it left off. It works over `ssh`.

Comment: Which of the two tar commands are you interrupting and what steps are you taking to cause the interruption?

Comment: I've considered rsync, but my current understanding is that rsync still processes one file at a time and therefore is slow for thousands of files on first sync.

I would be interrupting the create-archive tar command, mostly by execution time-limits, and the remote system's file would be overwritten (since nothing had yet been transferred to the local system).

Comment: If `tar c` is overwriting one of its source files, that's a bug. It should never do that. If this is GNU tar, please report it to [bug-tar](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-tar).

Comment: That does appear to be what's happening, and it has happened to me on several occasions. I'll check to see if anyone has posted it and do some more testing to see what conditions it overwrites under before submitting a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` should be a good tool for this.

If you want to keep using tar for the job and you do have enough space on the drive of your target machine, then you could copy over the whole file first and only untar it once the whole file has been transferred. Like:

`ssh user@domain "cd /var/www; tar zcvf - testing" | cat >/tmp/testing.tgz && tar xzvf /testing.tgz && rm -f /tmp/testing.tgz`

Possibly you might also want to use the `p` flag with tar, to preserve permissions.

Comment: Is that not how the command I posted works? I was under the impression I was creating the archive, transferring it, and then extracting the archive.

Comment: After further testing I realize I was wrong. The command I posted actually transfers as the files are compressed into the archive. Cool to know, thank you!